# How do I restore just part of a corrupted file on a zfs pool?

Tags: zfs

While running a scrub, `zfs status -xv` reports that a large (1TB) file has checksum errors. The docs say this can be fixed by "restoring the file" from a backup. I assume this just means `cp /backup/path/file /pool/path/file`. However this will take awhile since the file is so large, and I was wondering if there was some way to find exactly which offsets are corrupt so that I could simply use `dd` or similar to fix it very quickly.

Comment: Did you run a scrub? What happened before you asked this question?

Comment: @ewwhite Yes, I ran a scrub which found the error; Edited the q accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have another copy of the file, just copy it over.

However, it makes sense to understand what's wrong and what occurred with your setup.

What are your `zpool status -v` and `zfs list` outputs?

Did something happen to precipitate this error? Was there a hardware related event in this environment?